# access text strings only from text instance

Tags: python, matplotlib, text

I am trying to compile a list of the auto-generated strings for my xticklabels.

per [matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_xticklabels.htm), ax.get_xticklabels returns a list of text instances, e.g.:

```
[Text(-400.0, 0, '−400'), Text(-300.0, 0, '−300'), Text(-200.0, 0, '−200')]
```

I want:

```
['-400','-300','-200']
```

per [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.text.html), the string value I want is associated with 's' parameter of each text instances. How do I access these?

I have tried a number of variations, including:

```
[i.text for i in cbar.ax.get_xticklabels()]
[i.text() for i in cbar.ax.get_xticklabels()]
[i.s for i in cbar.ax.get_xticklabels()]
[i[2] for i in cbar.ax.get_xticklabels()]
```

and receive Attribute errors (for the first three) or Type errors (e.g. the fourth example).

This seems like it should be pretty straightforward.  What am I missing?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [`get_text()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text.get_text):

```
[i.get_text() for i in cbar.ax.get_xticklabels()]
```

Comment: Works good. As an aside, how do I access the x and y parameters? (.get_x() doesn't do it). Cheers

Comment: `get_position()` returns a tuple of `(x,y)` so x is `get_position()[0]` and y is `get_position()[1]`

Comment: Sweet as. Cheers!